# Add new columns and rows without changing the VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I created the Excel VBA code for a group project.

Now the team wants to add/rearrange columns and rows. The problem is those changes will make my code unusable.

How can I add/rearrange columns and rows without changing my VBA code?

```
Sub Stacy()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim myWs As Worksheet
    Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER")
    Set Rng1 = myWs.Range("A1:AJ4")
    Set Rng2 = myWs.Range("A975:AJ984")
    Application.Workbooks.Add
    Set WS = Application.ActiveSheet

    Rng1.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A1:AJ4")
    Rng2.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A5:AJ50")

    Rows(3).RowHeight = 36
    Rows(4).RowHeight = 64.5
    Rows("5:50").RowHeight = 15

    Columns(11).ColumnWidth = 11.57
    Columns(12).ColumnWidth = 30.43
    Columns(14).ColumnWidth = 15.57
    Columns(22).ColumnWidth = 14
    Columns(24).ColumnWidth = 13.71
    Columns(25).ColumnWidth = 13.71


    Set column1 = Columns("A:J")
        column1.Hidden = True
    Set column2 = Columns("R:T")
        column2.Hidden = True
    Set column3 = Columns("M:M")
        column3.Hidden = True
    Set column4 = Columns("U:U")
        column4.Hidden = True
    Set column5 = Columns("W:W")
        column5.Hidden = True
    Set column6 = Columns("Z:AJ")
        column6.Hidden = True

    [N1].Value = "Watenberg"
    [O1].Value = "Stacy"
    [N2].Value = "US Private Banking"

    Range("X15").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "'Total:"
    Range("Y15").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-10]C:R[-1]C)"
    Range("Y16").Select

'Protect the sheet
    Range("V1:V50").Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

    WS.SaveAs "L:\17_Year_End\2018\Distribution\Stacy"

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't really. Your code is using static values. You will need dynamic values to make your ask possible (which will still require you to add even more code). You can make use of some features like `Find and Replace All` to make the task easier, but the inevitable *Sub: Stacy 2.0* will have to happen

Comment: any way to change it to dynamic values?

Answer (score 0):

Might be tedious, but if you know what the columns are going to be titled, you can work off of that.

For example, lets say some of the column headers are "Purchase Date", "amount" and "Price".

```
'get last column variable, or if it wont change you can hard code in
lastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Loop through column headers, if statements for each one you care about
For i = 1 To lastCol
    If Cells(1, i).Value = "Purchase Date" Then
        Set Column1 = ActiveSheet.Columns(i)
    End If
    If Cells(1, i).Value = "amount" Then
        '... and so on ...
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: will try, thanks! Does that means the column will be locked as the new column name as Column 1..2..3, and any insert/delete wont affect that?

Comment: can I use the same way to lock the rows?

Comment: 1) I think so, but you could easily test for this.
2) Yes